# Disable fontsize change for RichTextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, font-size

In my application I am using `RichTextBox`es with readonly property set to True.
But the font size can still be changed using the mouse wheel and default windows keyboard shortcut for fontsize change (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>></kbd>/<kbd><</kbd>).

How do I disable `RichTextBox` font size change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the key combinations of `Control+Shift+<` or `Control+Shift+>`, you need to implement the following *KeyDown* event handler for your *RichTextBox* control:

```vb
 Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown

    ' disable the key combination of 
    '     "control + shift + <" 
    '     or
    '     "control + shift + >"
    e.SuppressKeyPress = e.Control AndAlso e.Shift And (e.KeyValue = Keys.Oemcomma OrElse e.KeyValue = Keys.OemPeriod)

End Sub
```

This code prevents the user from resizing the font in the given `RichTextBox` with keyboard commands.

To disable changing the font size by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> plus the mousewheel, the only way I know how to do this is to make a user `control` that inherits from `RichTextBox`.

Once you have done that the only thing you need to do is override the `WndProc` procedure so that it effectively disables any messages when the scrollwheel is moving and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is pressed.  See the code below for implementing a `UserControl` derived from the `RichTextBox`:

```vb
Public Class DerivedRichTextBox
    Inherits RichTextBox

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

        ' windows message constant for scrollwheel moving
        Const WM_SCROLLWHEEL As Integer = &H20A

        Dim scrollingAndPressingControl As Boolean = m.Msg = WM_SCROLLWHEEL AndAlso Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control

        'if scolling and pressing control then do nothing (don't let the base class know), 
        'otherwise send the info down to the base class as normal
        If (Not scrollingAndPressingControl) Then

            MyBase.WndProc(m)

        End If


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great! But how to disable Text Zoom in RichTextBox on Mouse Wheel?

Comment: I have edited my post to include disabling the mousewheel functionality.

Comment: Not sure that this covers all cases - what about for touchpad users who use gestures to change the zoom?

Comment: @amirazizkhani that is not a bad comment - it's a comment in `Visual Basic`

Comment: I just tested on my laptop's touch pad, and it emulated ctrl+scroll. The current method intercepted it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that offers disabling both scrollwheel and shortcuts zoom as actual options in the properties you get when editing the components in the designer view:

```
public class RichTextBoxZoomControl : RichTextBox
{
    private Boolean m_AllowScrollWheelZoom = true;
    private Boolean m_AllowKeyZoom = true;

    [Description("Allow adjusting zoom with [Ctrl]+[Scrollwheel]"), Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Boolean AllowScrollWheelZoom
    {
        get { return m_AllowScrollWheelZoom; }
        set { m_AllowScrollWheelZoom = value; }
    }

    [Description("Allow adjusting zoom with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[,] and [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[.]"), Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Boolean AllowKeyZoom
    {
        get { return m_AllowKeyZoom; }
        set { m_AllowKeyZoom = value; }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (!m_AllowScrollWheelZoom && (m.Msg == 0x115 || m.Msg == 0x20a) && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0)
            return;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.m_AllowKeyZoom && e.Control && e.Shift && (e.KeyValue == (Int32)Keys.Oemcomma || e.KeyValue == (Int32)Keys.OemPeriod))
            return;
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```